# Python array subtraction loops back to high number instead of giving negative value

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy, subtraction

Here is my code:
I'm using numpy and opencv

```
q = np.array(image)
q = q.reshape(-1, q.shape[2])
r = np.subtract(q,p)
print r
```

Basically what happens is if the value in my q array is greater than p the subtraction loops back up to 256 and subtracts whats left from there.  I'd rather get a value of 0 if the subtraction goes negative.  Does anybody know a good way to do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear? what you want to do exactly?

Comment: what is ``p``? What do you mean with "loops back"? that something like ``0-1 = 256`` happens?

Comment: I just don't understand why the subtraction doesn't work, I think that yes that that sort of loop back is happening, but I'm not sure.

p is the same as q just pulls the image from a different file

Comment: i'm not getting an overflow error, i still get values, but maybe.  This is my first image processing project so I'm new to it

Comment: Okay after checking:

Lets say my q is [x, 189, z]
Lets say my p is [m, 222, n]

My r becomes [x-m, 223, z-n]
 
223 is 256-33

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy uint8 pixel wrapping solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547557/numpy-uint8-pixel-wrapping-solution)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change to int16 which supports negative integers and set neg values to 0, your values are wrapping because you have `uint8's`:

```
arr1 = np.array([100, 200, 255],dtype=np.int16)
arr2 = np.array([180, 210, 100],dtype=np.int16)

sub_arr = np.subtract(arr1, arr2)
sub_arr[sub_arr < 0] = 0
print(sub_arr)
[  0   0 155]
```

To change you array you can use `array.astype(np.int16)` to change from `uint8` to `np.int16` and use the same to change back again after subtracting.

```
arr1 = np.array([100, 200, 255],dtype=np.uint8)
arr2 = np.array([180, 210, 100],dtype=np.uint8)
_arr2 = arr2.astype(np.int16)
sub_arr = np.subtract(arr1, _arr2)

sub_arr[sub_arr < 0] = 0
sub_arr = sub_arr.astype(np.uint8)
print(sub_arr)
```

Or also use [np.clip](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html):

```
arr1 = np.array([100, 200, 255],dtype=np.uint8)
arr2 = np.array([180, 210, 100],dtype=np.uint8)

sub_arr = np.subtract(arr1, arr2.astype(np.int16)).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
print(sub_arr)
[  0   0 155]
```

Comment: So you are sure there is no saturated subtraction available in numpy? Hmm.. surprrises me, as that is quite common and worth an optimized implementation.

Comment: @skrhee, no worries, I am far from a numpy expert so there may be a nicer way but this is as good as it gets for me ;)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thats as good as I need it! Have a great weekend

Comment: @skrhee, you too, glad it helped,

Comment: do you mean `string or a number`?

Answer (score 1):

You should add tag image processing. That gave the idea. I think, the problem is that if you have something like 10-11 you get a value of 255, but would prefer to stick at 0, right?

That is called wrapping (strictly: modulo arithmetics, which is normal for fixed-size integer variables) and also applies to addition (255+1 wraps to 0).

What you want is called saturation arithmetics. This will avoid wrap-around by saturating the result to the minimum and maximum.
Now, as I do not know numpy, I cannot tell you, if there is a saturated subtraction available, but that should be easy to find out for you.

Hope that my guess was right; your question leaves a lot of space for interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Given 2 arrays p and q of bytes, I've sucessfully computed the difference using numpy with the following line of code.

```
r = (p>q)*(p-q)+(p<q)*(q-p)
```