# convert image from CV_64F to CV_8U

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv

I want to convert an image of type `CV_64FC1` to `CV_8UC1` in Python using OpenCV.

In C++, using `convertTo` function, we can easily convert image type using following code snippet:

```
image.convertTo(image, CV_8UC1);
```

I have searched on Internet but unable to find any solution without errors. Any function in Python OpenCV to convert this?

Comment: Have you looked at [`cv2.cvtColor`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html)?

Comment: I think cv2.cvtColor is used for color space conversion. Can I use it for conversion of image type too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy uint8 pixel wrapping solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547557/numpy-uint8-pixel-wrapping-solution)

Comment: @rayryeng This question is regarding conversion from double to uint8 type using Python OpenCV which is solved using below answer and the question you mentioned have different problem statement.

Comment: Python with OpenCV uses numpy arrays as the fundamental data type. The linked answer is more generic because it *clips* the array before converting. The answer below does not do that and because of that, possible overflow will occur.

Comment: Yes. I understand this now. When I asked this question, I was novice to Python with OpenCV.

Comment: you may want to take a look to normalize, in case that you are over or under the possible values (0-255)... this is quite common with doubles. `cv2.normalize(image, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)` would do the trick. Notice that this will scale the image values to fit... This is for the cases when you have either values 0-1 or negative or more than 255 and you want to have a greyscale representation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can convert it to a Numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

# Convert source image to unsigned 8 bit integer Numpy array
arr = np.uint8(image)

# Width and height
h, w = arr.shape
```

It seems OpenCV Python APIs accept Numpy arrays as well. I've not tested it though. Please test it and let me know the result.

Comment: I am using OpenCV 3.2 with Python 3.6.2, while running the code, I am getting this error: AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'fromarray'.

Comment: @Jazz It seems `fromarray` is not required as of OpenCV 3.2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923669/what-is-the-replacement-of-cv2-cv-fromarray-in-opencv-3-2

Comment: In Python an OpenCV Mat object is basically a numpy array. They're very much interchangeable.

Comment: This is not working:  after applying `np.uint8(img)` and applying the result in `cv2.equalizeHist` the same error as in OP still occurs

Answer (score 7):

For those getting a black screen or lots of noise, you'll want to normalize your image first before converting to 8-bit. This is done with numpy directly as OpenCV uses numpy arrays for its images.

Before normalization, the image's range is from `4267.0` to `-4407.0` in my case. 
Now to normalize:

```
# img is a numpy array/cv2 image
img = img - img.min() # Now between 0 and 8674
img = img / img.max() * 255
```

Now that the image is between 0 and 255, we can convert to a 8-bit integer.

```
new_img = np.uint8(img)
```

This can also be done by `img.astype(np.uint8)`.

Comment: In the second statement, you need to divide img by img.max() - img.min()

Comment: @AdityaVerma That isn't necessary as `img.min() ` is `0`, so `img.max() - img.min()` is the same as `img.max()`. This is because I subtracted `img.min()`, so the image is between 0 and 8674.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. You're actually calculating `img.max()` again in the second statement. I was comparing it to what I did before, when I calculated both `min` and `max` at once using `minMaxLoc()`.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue and when I trying to convert the image 64F to CV_U8 I would end up with a black screen.

This [link](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html) will help you understand the datatypes and conversion. Below is the code that worked for me.

```
from skimage import img_as_ubyte
cv_image = img_as_ubyte(any_skimage_image)
```